# Return photo stacking rail to start

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

In isolation (73 years old) and trying to get my macro photo stacking rail to return to start without a limit switch.  I know the number of steps taken, so it is just a matter of reversing the motor.  My code (copied and pasted from other sites) works like a dream (10 steps, fire an IR camera trigger) and continues up to when I want to return (line 73) taking 100 shots or steps however many I want - no problem.

I started a void return loop (and terminated the loop) but the coding has me beat.  I have attached my code (might look terrible, but it works).  Can anyone help out this old guy and give me the code to counter clockwise 1000 steps?

Thanks fellas
David

```
[code]
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <MultiStepper.h>


int smDirectionPin = 2; //Direction pin
int smStepPin = 3; //Stepper pin
int Distance = 0; // records the number of steps we have taken
byte numRepeats = 0;
byte maxRepeats = 100;
int smFirePin = 13;  //Trigger pin
#define fire 13 

 void setup(){
  /*Sets all pin to output; the microcontroller will send them(the pins) bits, it will not expect to receive any bits from thiese pins.*/
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);  //Direction Pin
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);  //Step Pin
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  //LED pin
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  pinMode(smDirectionPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(smStepPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); //Open Serial connection for debugging
} 

void loop(){
   if (numRepeats < maxRepeats) {
   move1Step();  
   Distance = Distance + 1; //record this step to see if we are et the end of our move

  if (Distance == 10)
  {
 if (digitalRead(2) == LOW)
 {
  digitalWrite(2 , LOW);
 }
 else
 {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 }
 Distance = 0;
 numRepeats ++;
 delay(3000);
{
    trigger();
}
   }
 }
}
void move1Step() {
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(750);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(750);
}
// Power on the IR trigger circuit to fire the camera
void trigger()
{
    delay(1000); // wait for vibration to settle
    digitalWrite(fire, HIGH); // take the picture
    delay(2000); // wait for that to happen
    digitalWrite(fire, LOW); // disable the IR circuit again
}

// Advance the motor by one step
void step()
{
  digitalWrite(step, HIGH); //Trigger one step forward
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(step, LOW); //Pull step pin low so it can be triggered again
  delay(1);
}

  void return();

{
  digitalWrite(smDirectionPin, HIGH); 
  /*Slowly turns the motor 1600 steps*/
  for (int i = 0; i <200; i++){
    digitalWrite(smStepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(700);
    digitalWrite(smStepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(700);
  }

  while(1) { }        
}





[/code]
```

Comment: code, such as this, makes no sense ... `if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) { digitalWrite(2 , LOW); } else { digitalWrite(2, LOW); }` ... that whole block can  be replaced by `digitalWrite(2, LOW);`

Comment: `return` is a reserved word, so you should rename the function to, for example, `returnHome`. You also need to remove the `;` at the end of that line of code.

Comment: Plus your indentation is a mess. Pick an indentation style and then follow it religiously.  As it is the code is quite hard to read.

Comment: Gerben has provided a solution, your observation have been noted and accepted, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. Removed duplicate and unused code. I used a `for`-loop to make it run for 100 repetitions.

Feel free to let me know if you have any more questions, or if there are things that aren't clear.

```
// You aren't using these libraries, so I commented them out
//#include <AccelStepper.h>
//#include <MultiStepper.h>


int smDirectionPin = 2; //Direction pin
int smStepPin = 3; //Stepper pin
int smFirePin = 13;  //Trigger pin

byte maxRepeats = 100;

void setup()
{
  /*Sets all pin to output; the microcontroller will send them(the pins) bits, it will not expect to receive any bits from thiese pins.*/
  pinMode(smDirectionPin, OUTPUT);  //Direction Pin
  pinMode(smStepPin, OUTPUT);  //Step Pin
  pinMode(smFirePin, OUTPUT);  //Fire pin
  digitalWrite(smDirectionPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(smStepPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(smFirePin,LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600); //Open Serial connection for debugging
} 

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(smDirectionPin, LOW); // set stepper motor to run forwards

  for( byte i=0; i<maxRepeats; i++ ) // run the following section 100 times
  {
    //move 10 steps forward
    for( byte j=0; j<10; j++ )
    {
      move1Step();  
    }

    // wait and take a photo
    delay(3000);// there is already a delay in the `trigger` function, so this like could be removed
    trigger();
  }


  // return the stepper motor to the starting position
  digitalWrite(smDirectionPin, HIGH); // set stepper motor to run in reverse
  for( byte i=0; i<maxRepeats; i++ ) // run the following section 100 times
  {
    //move 10 steps backwards
    for( byte j=0; j<10; j++ )
    {
      move1Step();  
    }
  }

  // Do nothing
  while(1){ }
}

void move1Step()
{
  digitalWrite(smStepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(750);
  digitalWrite(smStepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(750);
}

// Power on the IR trigger circuit to fire the camera
void trigger()
{
    delay(1000); // wait for vibration to settle
    digitalWrite(smFirePin, HIGH); // take the picture
    delay(2000); // wait for that to happen
    digitalWrite(smFirePin, LOW); // disable the IR circuit again
}
```

Comment: Gerben, I will follow your advice on deleting the delay, you should publish this, many in micro photography would be grateful, works like a charm. Fantastic.

Comment: If you delete the delay, you might have to increase the `delay(1000)`. As currently it waits 4 seconds to prevent any movement from vibrations. You'd have to see how short the values can be, or just be a bit more patient. Glad it helped you.